# Everything I start from a worker role has no interface, why?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-worker-roles

I am having a very bad moment executing a process from internet explorer.. I am supposed to call internet explorer from a worker role process to perform some operations..but internet explorer is executing with no visible interface...

This is my code :

```
psi.FileName = "D:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe";
psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
psi.ErrorDialog = false;
psi.UseShellExecute = false;
psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized;
psi.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
psi.RedirectStandardInput = false;
psi.RedirectStandardError = true;
psi.Arguments = fileLocation;
exeProcess = Process.Start(psi);
started = true;
exeProcess.PriorityClass = ProcessPriorityClass.RealTime;
```

Can you please help me? I need to execute internet explorer with a visible interface.

Comment: WHY WHY WHY WHY WHY WHY WHY WHY WHY!!! A worker role is like a window service. In the cloud. With no User Interface ~visible~ to a human. WTF are you trying to do, man! *this post is killing me*

Comment: I am trying to execute a process on a server. I just want to render something on internet explorer and make a print screen..its a very particular case.

Comment: @Pure.Krome - just a tiny clarification: A worker role is not a Windows Service - it's a full Windows Server virtual machine, just without IIS running. But you're right in that there's no UI exposed.

Comment: @DavidMakogon yep - that's right. I was just simplifying things.

Comment: In your code, I see that you're setting "CreateNoWindow" to true. Can you try by changing it to false?

Answer (score 2):

Running process that normally requires completely functioning Windows desktop is unlikely to run correctly from service as there is no UI/windows associated with services. You should be able to reproduce the same behavior by trying to instantiate such application from a service (i.e. IIS) on local machine running under some service account.

If you need to render web pages on server it would be better to either use external service or specifically designed "headless browser" like PhantomJS.